# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation in drag and drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, micro-frontend, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm using angular cdk drag and drop but while drag i'm not able to see my drag element it become hidden and i can see this console error

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.drag-drop.js:468

In coding not written anything for drag we did only for drop and not added event.preventDefault() in any line.

**Note**:Facing this issue only if i run this application inside another application like microfrontend.

Added passive false for HostListener

```
            `@HostListener('cdkDropListExited', ['$event'])
                keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
                    console.log('cdkDropListExited');
                    { passive: false }
                }

            @HostListener('cdkDropListEntered', ['$event'])
                keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
                    console.log('cdkDropListEntered');
                    { passive: false }
                }

            @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
                keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
                    console.log('touchstart');
                    { passive: false }
            }`
```

But this are not working